# Laravel 8 storage/framework/cache/data/ee folder sets user as root:root rather than apache:apache permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, jwt, centos

I have a Laravel 8 application, running on a Cent OS 8.4 VM. I'm using the [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) package by Tymondesigns to implement auth on my project, it's being used an an API.

When I set up the project on the server, and deploy it, the `storage` folder in Laravel is moved to the `shared` directory as part of the [deployer](https://deployer.org/) project, and for some reason, despite setting permissions of the `storage` folder, I'm seeing that not every folder, in particular the `ee` cache folder has the wrong permissions, and I'm getting a permission denied error thrown by the JWT auth package:

> file_put_contents(/var/www/project-beacon-api/releases/37/storage/framework/cache/data/ee/67/ee673b1cd21b0cd9eca15c240d66269df17f9b3a): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I can't understand why I'm getting this error, and for as long as I've worked with Laravel, setting permissions of the `storage` folder to `755` / `775` has never worked, and trying to open the website always throws a permission denied.

What am I missing in the permissions configuration, what do I need to run to solve this once and for all?

[image: permissions]

It always seems to be the `ee` folder!

Comment: make sure the nginx/apache server user(www-data) has the rights to those folders and is the owner.

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because of the laravel cache
Before running this command
Go to .env file in you project you will find

```
CACHE_DRIVER = file
```

then change the cache driver to this

```
CACHE_DRIVER = array
```

When it comes to using cache in Laravel you have 3 possible "families" that you should consider:

Temporary/Debug

array

Always available

file
database
APC (I would not trust this one since PHP7)

Dedicated

Redis

Memcached

Since you can easily replace the cache drivers you don't need to pick one based on your use case, but more based on your server needs/load and possibilities.

For example on your development machine, I suggest using a file, since this way you won't need any extra software clogging your PC plus you gain the ability to quickly clear the cache even if you do something really bad like breaking the artisan command. All you need to do is delete the storage/framework folder and you have a fresh instance again (make sure to regenerate the .gitignore files from your repository after that)

For your main server, you have to think about your possibilities. If you have one of those free hosting websites you almost certainly won't be able to install any new software, so you can consider using a file or database. Even though the database will probably be faster than a file, it is in most cases the weakest point of your website, and trying to push even more data into that bottleneck is not a good idea, that is why I would suggest against using it, and instead stick to files.

If you have a dedicated server then you should definitely pick Memcached or Redis. Which one of the two? It depends on many factors, and you can find a lot of comparisons online, just look for one. I personally prefer Redis because of its ability to persist data, but either one is a good solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What's this doing? Difference between file and array?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RyanH I have updated my answer you can read it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have ownership for your entire project (user:group) [use `ls -la` to see ownership in your project root folder]

If not right, use chown:
`sudo chown -R yourUserName:www-data /path/to/project`

If ownership's ok, just set permissions for storage folder like that: `sudo chmod -R 775 storage/` so you can have the right to write